# React Navigation + Native Base => props.navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I'm trying to style my TabNavigator using Native Base, but I always get "`props.navigation.navigate` is not a function" and I have no idea why.

This is my TabNavigator:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, Icon, Footer, FooterTab } from 'native-base';

import CameraRouter from './CameraRouter';
import Feed from '../components/Feed';

const MainRouter = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: Feed,
    },
    Camera: {
      screen: CameraRouter,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarVisible: false,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button
              vertical
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Feed')}
            >
              <Icon name="bowtie" />
              <Text>Lucy</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('CameraRouter')}
            >
              <Icon name="briefcase" />
              <Text>Nine</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
            >
              <Icon name="headset" />
              <Text>Jade</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
);

export default MainRouter;
```

Which I call here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import MainRouter from './config/MainRouter';

import reducers from './reducers';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainRouter />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What is wrong with my code? I used this guide to get an idea of the usage:
http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/navigation/StackNavigationExample.html

Thank you guys!

Comment: Still need help with this

Answer (score 1):

if want to implement with `react-navigation 3.0` with `native-base 2.13` then below code will work.

```
 import { createBottomTabNavigator,createStackNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
  import React from 'react';
  import { Button, Text, Icon, Footer, FooterTab } from 'native-base';

  import Home from './containers/Home';
  import CreateCase from './containers/CreateCase';
  import Profile from './containers/Profile';
  import Performance from './containers/Performance';

  const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home : {
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions: {
              header: null,
            }
          },
      Create:  {
        screen: CreateCase,
        navigationOptions: {
          title: "Generate Case",
        }
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Home"
    }
  );

  const Main = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Home: { screen: MainNavigator },
      Profile: { screen: Profile },
      Performance: {screen: Performance}
    },
    {
      tabBarComponent: props => {
        return (
          <Footer>
            <FooterTab>
              <Button
                vertical
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
              >
                <Icon name="bowtie" />
                <Text>Lucy</Text>
              </Button>
              <Button
                vertical
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
              >
                <Icon name="briefcase" />
                <Text>Nine</Text>
              </Button>
              <Button
                vertical
              >
                <Icon name="headset" />
                <Text>Jade</Text>
              </Button>
            </FooterTab>
          </Footer>
        );
      }
    }
  );

  export default createAppContainer(Main);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html 
This doc mentions that navigation props is not available to every component by default only the screen components have it.

if you wish to access this prop in other components then you either pass this prop to the component where it is needed or you use what is called '[withNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)'

Comment: What is the difference between my components and a screen component?

Comment: screen components are defined in your navigator as key value pair.

Comment: const TabMenu = TabNavigator({
    NameOfTab1: { screen: componentToBeDIsplayedAtTab1 },
    NameOfTab2: { screen: componentToBeDIsplayedAtTab2 },
    NameOfTab3: { screen: componentToBeDIsplayedAtTab3 }
  },

Answer (score 0):

I think the props aren't being passed through from your App component, could you try this?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainRouter {...props}/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but props aren't defined in the App component

Comment: Even using this.props, I can't get the function to work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem: I had to add a root StackNavigator

Comment: can you add final working code here? I am trying to achieve this.